# Machine running Ubuntu server 16.4.3 shuts down if no monitor plugged to it

Tags: 16.04, server, bios

I installed Ubuntu server 16.4.3 on my machine Advantech Ecu4784 When I switch on the machine without monitor plugged to it then after about 1 minute the machine shuts down. If I plug in the screen and then switch it on then the Ubuntu does not switch itself off after 1 minute. How do I control this feature and have the machine running even if there is no screen plugged to the computer?